# Displaying new products with paging enabled

Tags: magento1.6.2

I am struggling with a situation for last 2 days that i want to display the new products using pagination and all sorting and per page option enabled on the template i saw that there is no code for under core Block/New.php for such kind of functionality any one have solved this before please help to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

## CMS Block

This is described in the magento wiki:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

```
    {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

I'm not sure, but I think you have to mark the products as new from ... until in the product's configuration.

## Own block

The alternative is to implement a block like this:

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Newest extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{

    /**
     * returns the product collection, ordered by created_at date
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            return $this->_productCollection;
        }
        $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
        $collection->addOrder(
            'created_at',
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC
        );
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately this not what i was looking for i am setting the product as new using new from date and new to date attributes and this is what new.phtml phtml is built to display new products this is working but the pagination and other sorting options are not coming :-(

Comment: just add the toolbar in your `layout.xml`. The block is extended from the product_list, so it should work with the toolbar out of the box

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Did it solve your problem? Please mark it as solution. If not, what's the problem?

Comment: Won't work as $collection would have only products of the specific category, not all new products that marked New from date